# Не знаю как в переменные правильно запихнуть $_POST

Tags: php, массивы, регистрация

Ребят подскажите, есть ошибки:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: email in C:\laragon\www\zam\index.php on line 16
Call Stack
( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\laragon\www\zam\index.php on line 16
Call Stack
```

Есть код:

```
public function register($email, $password)
    {
        $data = [
            'email'=> $email,
            'password' => md5($password)
        ];
        
        $this->db->store('users', $data);
    }

$auth = new Auth($db);
$auth->register($email, $password);
```

Не знаю как в $email, $password запихнуть вот это

```
$data =[
"email" => $_POST['email'],
"password" => $_POST['password']
];
```

что бы "$auth->register($email, $password);" именно к ним обращался

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Если нужно передавать в функцию из $_POST, так это и сделайте в чем проблема то? Но если важно "распаковать" $_POST в переменные можно попробовать extract($_POST). Тогда поля массива будут доступны как отдельные переменные.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, у Вас проблема с передачей параметров в функцию.

Попробуйте так:

```
$auth->register($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
```